# Windows exclusive control of audio device

Tags: windows-10, audio

Even though I disabled `Allow applications to take exclusive control of this device` - I still get an application "hijacking" the audio channel, in example I would be speaking on Skype, and then a Ping sound from Messenger or Hangouts would mute my Skype for 5 seconds or so. How to prevent that?

[image]